# Is it possible to execute a shell script in an Android phone?

Tags: android, linux, shell, root

I have an Android 2.2.2 phone (LG P350f). It's rooted with Superuser and I have just installed Android Terminal Emulator. I log in as root (su) and try to execute a simple script, lol.sh, which is supposed to echo a string. I get the following output:

```
# ./lol.sh
./lol.sh: permission denied
```

Obviously I have tried to set permissions, but after typing:

```
# chmod 777 lol.sh
```

I still get this:

```
# ls -l lol.sh
----rwxxr-x ...
```

The file resides in the sd card, I will try to move it elsewhere, any other ideas?

Comment: You can use `Process` in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Most filesystems in Android are usually mounted with the 'noexec' option. Make sure you place your script on a filesystem which does *not* have that option set.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You can, of course, always invoke it as “sh lol.sh” instead, to circumvent the “noexec”…

Answer (score 1):

From your question it seems you have root access (the `#` in the shell prompt), so move your script to a filesystem mounted with `exec` permission for example:

```
# mv lol.sh /data/lol.sh
# chmod 700 /data/lol.sh
# /data/lol.sh
```

Comment: root@user:/data # ./run_script
/system/bin/sh: ./run_script: No such file or directory

root@user:/data # ls -l run_script
-rwxrwxrwx root     root         5861 2016-11-14 07:31 run_script

Comment: Hi Diego, despite of copying to /data I get the same error. I checked in mount /data was not mounted with noexec. What is the reason